# Time series to forecast a probability

Tags: regression, time-series, probability, forecasting, arima

I'm looking to forecast a time series, that is, forecast the next period give historical time series data. At the end of the day, what I want is to forecast a probability. The metric that I'm forecasting follows the beta distribution and so, the parameter that I am working with are alpha and beta. What I have tried so far, is a SARIMA model for each parameters separately, and then combining the two afterwards to create a probability. The issue that I keep running into with regression frameworks is getting results that are above 1 or below 0. Is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Furthermore, I'm working in Python for this, so for the sake of keeping things not too complex I would say that I don't have much of an ability to perform a beta regression.

Comment: Is your data probabilities or 0/1 observations that you want to forecast a probability for?

Comment: my data comes in the from of alpha and beta parameters (success and failures) that represent parameters of a beta distribution, so they can effectively be turned into a probability (a/a+b)

Comment: Are they actually successes and failures, in which case you are dealing with Binomial distributions (with different parameters) for your data at each period?  And you want to forecast the probability parameter?

Comment: Yes they are actual successes and failures at each step, I suppose that makes sense to look at it as a binomial distribution, however, the typical parameters for a binomial (at least afaik) are n & p and there is a different binomial distribution at each step. Yes i would like to forecast a probability, but it would be ok to first forecast successes and failures separately and then use those parameters to define a probability if that works better.

Comment: Does http://strata.uga.edu/8370/rtips/proportions.html seem relevant?  The idea would be to transform the observed percentages of success, build a time series model on the transformed observations, then invert the transform for the model predictions to get back to percentages.

Comment: Logit transform the probabilities, run a time series regression on it, then use the sigmoid to transform it back?

Answer (score 0):

If you were working in R, packages [KFAS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KFAS/) and [ZIM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ZIM/index.html) might be useful. I do not know of similar software in Python.